# Суть выражения «не обессудь»

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, глаголы

Есть ощущение, что это выражение логически неверно. "Обессудить" по логике должно быть "оставить без суда", не зря ведь там приставка "без(с)", а тогда смысл выражения — не оставьте без суда.
Надо либо убирать "не", либо приставку "без", а иначе это что-то вроде двойного отрицания (*не не осудите*). Ведь так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Обессудить" по логике должно быть "оставить без суда",

Да нет, не так. Не *"без суда"*, а *"без осуждения"* тогда уж. Это было бы еще по вашей логике. А суд-то как раз может и оправдать. Вот *"без суда [осудить]"* - это да, сплошное несчастье, то, чего можно просить не делать.  *Обессудить* - это, если уж искать прямое соответствие, будет *"[наказать] без суда", "лишить права на суд".*

> а тогда смысл выражения - не оставьте без суда, надо либо убирать
>   "не", либо приставку "без", а иначе это что-то вроде двойного
>   отрицания (не не осудите), ведь так?

Ну в каком-то смысле - да.

Но все дело в том, что глагол "бессудить" не несет в себе того отрицания, о котором вы говорите. У него другое значение. Фактически он эквивалентен современному значению *"осудить"*.

https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C
(Это по Фасмеру).

А само слово *суд*, в современном значении закрепившее лишь этакое "карательное" значение, исходно значило *"правда, справедливость". "Бессудить"*, таким образом, - это "оставить без правды". Отсюда и современное значение *"обессудить"* - *гневаться, раздражаться*.

Справедливости ради надо заметить, что не только само слово *"суд"*, лежащее в основе, изменилось, но и это исходное значение самого слова *"обессудить"* испытало некоторое изменение смысла и стало сейчас означать просто-напросто *"относиться строго"*. Но это уже поддается логике, тут совсем не столь разительный дрейф значения, как могло бы показаться из ваших соображений.

Comment: "А само слово суд, в современном значении закрепившее лишь этакое "карательное" значение .....Это может быть так в подсознании жителей отдельно взятой страны только?

Comment: М_Г  Ну мы о русском язіке говорим, нет? ))) У других народов и слово другое, вряд ли у англичан или китайцев "суд" имеет похожую этимологию. Я имел в виду, что "суд" в значении "правда", "справедливость" сейчас совершенно невозможно, максимум - орган, который эту справедливость ищет.

Comment: Если, по-вашему, "суд" исходно значило "правда, справедливость", то значит ли это что фразу "не судите и не судимы будете" в то время должны были переводить используя иное слово? Или как раз библия и виновна в негативном "дрейфе" смысла?

Comment: @Basilius это не по моему, а по Фасмеру. Библия тут не при чем. А значение глагола "судить"  в евангельском первоисточнике вполне соответвует такому значению ("обсуждать", "давать оценку"). Оно, кстати, и не очень изменилось с тех пор.

Answer (score 4):

Примеры:

Вечер добрый. Припоздал, не обессудьте. Плохая я хозяйка, это верно, вы уж не обессудьте. Поэтому в моих записках возможна путаница, так что не обессудьте.

Смысл везде понятный: извините, не осуждайте меня заранее (не выслушав), разрешите мне объяснить ситуацию.

В русском языке существует формант ОБЕЗ/ОБЕС...И: обесточить, обезглавить, обезличить, обесцветить, все эти глаголы имеют значение "лишить чего-либо.

Обессудить - лишить суда, но суда СПРАВЕДЛИВОГО, ПРАВИЛЬНОГО. Поэтому "не обессудьте" - это "не лишайте справедливого суда, выслушайте мои объяснения и примите их в качестве оправдания.

Comment: На деле употребление выражения "не обессудьте" не предполагает изложения и выслушивания дальнейших объяснений.

Comment: В итоге вопрос сводится к современному негативному смыслу слова "суд", однако всё-таки сложно поверить в древний положительный его смысл учитывая возраст фразы "не судите, и несудимы будете", это что же тогда отказ от понимания ближнего и беспристрастности?

Comment: Объяснения уже даны заранее, говорящий просит их учесть перед тем, как вы составите о нем мнение, возможно негативное, или он просто заранее извиняется, сознавая свою "вину".  Но всё это относится к  происхождению устойчивого выражения, смысл которого в современном языке сводится к просьбе извинить какие-то недостатки.

Comment: В основном все отвечающие говорят об одном и том же, расхождение лишь в деталях. Я думаю, даже во временя Даля говорящий как бы просил не осуждать его заранее (до справедливого суда), но он не ждал суда от своего собеседника,  собеседника просили всего лишь не осуждать заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Взгляните на корень слова. Глагол «судить» можно также истолковать как «выражать своё мнение» или «обдумывать». Таким образом, смысл фразы, возможно, заключается в просьбе не отнестись необдуманно, не оставить без внимания, проявить максимальную чуткость.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду судить в положительном смысле, как в фразе "посудите сами"? Но приставка "о" делает его негативным как "осудить" "осуждение", может она и не делала его таковым во время возникновения этого выражения

Comment: Версия интересная, хота и противоречит словарю. Словарь говорит, что "не обессудьте" это "не судите", а по вашему - наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Нам поможет В.И. Даль: Бессудить кого (бесстудить? осудить без суда?), осуждать, охуждать, хулить, винить пересудами, бранить, поносить, корить.

Видимо, слово "бессудить" означало не "оставить без суда", а "осудить без суда".

Comment: С Далем вообще поаккуратнее надо. Как этимолог он не такой уж и авторитетный. С какой колокольни тут "бесстудить"? Это какая-то народная "спинджачная-какбынетная" этимология. Но вывод у вас срвершенно правильный. "Оставить без суда" - то есть без права на справедливость.

Answer (score 1):

У Даля [ОБЕЗСУЖИВАТЬ](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=kt1bAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1159&dq=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%22%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBzcDju5fVAhVFEpoKHersD7sQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%22%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%22&f=false), {обезсудить} (кого) : не давать суда, **обвинять без суда**; //обвинять, осуждать, порицать, охаять, охуждать, (особенно) заглазно, бесславить. {Не обезсудьте на угощении, на слове}, не осудите, извините. {Сосед обезсудился}, подпал осужденью, порицанью, бесславию. {Обезсудчивый}, охочий до пересудов, до осужденья.

Это дает разгадку: не обессудь - не спеши с обвинениями.

Answer (score -1):

Какая-то бессмыслица, не осуждайте.

Просьба "не обессудить" по всему изначально призвана не оставлять без суда, что-то вроде "посуди сам". Например: Посуди сам (не обессудь), у меня не было другого выбора.

Однако с течением времени и неграмотного использования (я так подразумеваю в каких-то определённых средах, например, из-за частого использования в жаргоне какой-то субкультуры) давно смысл этого выражения изменился, буквально вывернулся наизнанку и стал аналогом фразы "не судите строго".

Однако по Ожегову 
"ОБЕССУ́ДИТЬ (разг.) просьба не отнестись слишком строго, не осудить [обычно говорится при угощении кого-н., предложении чего-н.]".

То есть можно подразумевать, что изначально это слово применялось без частицы НЕ. 
Пример: Эти печеньки пёк я сам, обессудьте, пожалуйста.

Но часто, к сожалению, люди мало задумываются над тем, что и как они делают и над тем, что говорят в том числе. Язык меняется со временем, иногда по причине невежества.

Comment: *по всему изначально призвана не оставлять без суда* совершенно верно. Но смысл вы трактуете неправильно. Оставить без суда - оищить права на суд, на объективное рассмотрение, Так что ваше предположения о подмене смысла и прочая "конспирология"  не имеют под собой почвы.

Comment: Вы уверены, что нет почвы? Прошу ознакомиться.
Не обессудь — не обессу/дьте разг. Просьба проявить снисхождение, не быть слишком строгим; не осуди(те), не взыщи(те) Угощение у нас небогатое, уж вы не обессудьте!
Какая конспирология, гражданин? Сомневаюсь, что вы внимательно отнеслись к вопросу и к моему сообщению. Вы тут мимоходом? Вот и идите дальше.

Comment: *Прошу ознакомиться* - а что это доказывает-то? Вы не современное значение подменили, вы в историческом запутались. А оно не так уж далеко от современного. Читайте другие ответы и не пишите "бессмыслица", если не поняли.

Comment: Цитата из Ожегова в ответе сознательно искажена с точностью до наоборот с целью подвести под неё логику ответа. Ставлю минус.